# Keras: ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I'm working on implementing a sequence-to-sequence model with an attention mechanism using TensorFlow and Keras. My code is based on a combination of LSTM layers for both the encoder and decoder, with an attention mechanism in between. However, I'm encountering a "Graph disconnected" error during the creation of the decoder model.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense, Attention
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers

def seq2seq(latent_dim, num_input_tokens, num_target_tokens):
    # Define the Encoder
    encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, num_input_tokens),
                          name='encoder_data')
    encoder_lstm = LSTM(hidden_size,
                        return_sequences=True, return_state=False,
                        name='encoder_lstm_1')
    encoder_outputs = encoder_lstm(encoder_inputs)

    encoder_lstm = LSTM(hidden_size,
                        return_sequences=True, return_state=True,
                        name='encoder_lstm_2')
    encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder_lstm(encoder_outputs)
    encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]
   
    # Define the Decoder
    decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, num_target_tokens))
    decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
    decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs, initial_state=encoder_states)
    
    # Define the Attention mechanism
    attention = Attention()
    attention_outputs = attention([encoder_outputs, decoder_outputs])
    
    # Connect the Attention outputs to the Decoder
    decoder_dense = Dense(num_target_tokens, activation='softmax')
    decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(attention_outputs)
    
    model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
    adam = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])  # Assuming truncated_acc and truncated_loss are custom metrics

    # Define the Encoder model for inference
    encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)
    
    # Define the Decoder model for inference
    decoder_state_input_h = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
    decoder_state_input_c = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
    decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c]
    decoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = decoder_lstm(
        decoder_inputs, initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)
    decoder_states = [state_h, state_c]
    decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(attention([encoder_outputs, decoder_outputs]))
    decoder_model = Model(
        [decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs,
        [decoder_outputs] + decoder_states)
    
    return model, encoder_model, decoder_model


hidden_size = 512
nb_inp_token = 20
nb_tar_token = 20

model, encoder_model, decoder_model = seq2seq(
    hidden_size, nb_inp_token, nb_tar_token)
```

The issue arises specifically from the line where I'm defining the decoder model for inference:

`decoder_model = Model([decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs, [decoder_outputs] + decoder_states)`

ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, 20), dtype=tf.float32, name='encoder_data'), name='encoder_data', description="created by layer 'encoder_data'") at layer "encoder_lstm_1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

My understanding of the error message is that encoder_lstm_1 can't process the input that it recieves from encoder_data, what seems strange to me, because model and encoder_model are working fine.
I also tried to rename all variable names, so I don't override them.

I'm not sure how to properly connect the attention mechanism outputs, decoder LSTM outputs, and decoder states in this context. Could someone please guide me on how to correctly structure the decoder part of the model to avoid this "Graph disconnected" error?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.